# Push multiple elements in one key

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, array-push

```
foreach ($hash as $h) {
    array_push($users, $h['entities']['urls'][0]['expanded_url']);
}
```

I also want to push `$h['created_at']` into `$users` so it would look something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
       (
           [0] => 'http://www.google.com'
           [1] => 'Sun May 17 06:32:14 +0000 2015'

        )
)
```

Is there a way I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood right, you want array of arrays

```
foreach ($hash as $h)
        $users[] = array($h['entities']['urls'][0]['expanded_url'], $h['created_at'] );
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is this:

```
$user[] = $h['created_at'];
```